# Determinate if exist a function $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R $ such that: $f(x+y)=max(xy,x)+min(xy,y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions

Determinate if it exists a function $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R $ such that:
$$f(x+y)=\max(xy,x)+\min(xy,y)$$

My try was to define $(x,y)=(2,2)$ because in this way $x+y=xy$, and it didn't work, but I don't know if this is enough to determinate that this function does not exist.

Any hints?

Comment: If $(x,y)=(2,2)$ we get $f(4)=8$  This is certainly not enough to show the function doesn't exit.  Try some other values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such function can not exist, because it would not be well-defined. 
For $r\in\mathbb{R}$ the function $f$ could possibly take infinite solutions, since you can write $r=x+y$ in an infinite amout of ways.

For example: $1=\frac12+\frac12$ and $1=2-1$.

Then $f(\frac12+\frac12)=\max(\frac14,\frac12)+\min(\frac14,\frac12)=\frac12+\frac14=\frac34$

Otherwise:

$f(2-1)=\max(-2,2)+\min(-2,-1)=2+(-2)=0$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Let $x=1$ and $y=2$. Then let $x=2$ and $y=1$.